# Insert NULL values into Hive with dataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, insert

I'm trying insert values into a Hive table, and if every column has a value there are no problems, but I need to insert NULL value in one of that columns. 
I'm doing it in that way:

```
val errorsToAlert = List(("source1", "table1","27-01-2002", null))
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(errorsToAlert).toDF("source", 
"table_name", "open_date", "close_date")
data.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("management.alerts")
```

I've tried with NULL and None, but both represent this error:

> 17/06/26 11:59:38 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw
>   exception:
>        scala.MatchError: scala.None.type (of class 
>        scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueSingleType)
>        scala.MatchError: scala.None.type (of class 
>        scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueSingleType)

Comment: Thats because you have only one row in your data with close_date as null which is treated as None type and not StringType. You have to either explicitly define a schema or add another line with not null value in close_date column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is completely unrelated to Hive. If you check the type of `errorsToAlert` you'll see it is:

```
List[(String, String, String, Null)]
```

and `scala.Null` is not an acceptable input for `Dataset`.

If required type itself is nullable you can specify it explicitly:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("source1", "table1","27-01-2002", null: String)
))
```

otherwise use `scala.Option`:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("source1", "table1","27-01-2002", None: Option[Int])
))
```

Comment: I don't think "close_date" is of type `Int` (your last line)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Fair point, but both `Strings` and supported `java.sql` types are covered by the first case, so this is mostly for completeness.